# How do I use WebHost Manager to change the nonsecure mail server

Tags: email, cpanel, whm

For my WHM I want to change the non secure incoming/outgoing server from `mail.example.com` to just `example.com` like the secure server settings is. Is this possible?

[image]

Comment: This is off topic here and belongs on serverfault.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Rob cPanel/WHM related questions are welcome here depending on the nature of the issue. Since this is a MX/DNS/VIRTUAL HOST host related issue its welcome here.

Comment: @NinjaPanda, Its unlikely you have the option to change the virtual host on the mail server since this is set normally by your web host unless your using a VPS/Dedicated server with a full cpanel license.

Comment: @Simon yes I have a vps Server with full root access

Answer (score 1):

*You need to edit the MX records for the account which can be done like so:*

1. Login to WHM
2. Find: DNS Functions in the menu
3. Click: Edit MX Entry
4. Find your domain, select it and then click edit
5. Under MX Destination change `mail.example.com` to `example.com`
6. Click save

To connect to the mail server using a secure connection such as port 993 and 465 you will need to setup SSL, this is a huge topic and you will need to find a tutorial.